# Sacar de un String una sub cadena desde x hasta y

Tags: javascript

Teniendo la cadena `{"1":{"2":{"4":{"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}},"5":{"7":{}}},"3":{}}}`
¿Cómo puedo sacar la sub cadena `"4":{"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}}` usando javascript?

Comment: Puedes usar [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) o [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En javascript eso representa un objeto, por lo tanto puedes navegar por el mediante índices, en tu ejemplo

```
ppal = {"1":{"2":{"4":{"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}},"5":{"7":{}}},"3":{}}}
// Podemos acceder a todo el objeto del índice 1
sub1 = ppal["1"]
// sub1 contiene {"2":{"4":{"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}},"5":{"7":{}}},"3":{}}

// Después a todo el objeto del índice 2
sub2 = ppal["1"]["2"] 
// sub2 contiene {"4":{"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}},"5":{"7":{}}}

// Y si solo quisieras el objeto con índice 4
sub3 = ppal["1"]["2"]["4"]
 // sub3 contiene {"6":{"9":{}},"8":{}}
```